# asp.net Server Error in '/' application in vs 2015 from host which I bought

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to publish a website which I built on asp.net framework 4.6 which works quite well when I start from IIS.

What I mean is that I can reach to admin panel through login page however when I try to reach from the host I can not reach to the admin page.

It gives this error "Server Error in '/' Application.  The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.   Requested URL: /admin.aspx"

Comment: So? Did you make sure that a file named admin.aspx is deployed to the root of your web application on the host?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still, it is giving the same error. @mason